# Android getchildcount return to total before scrolling

Tags: android, scroll

I am going to custom a scroll listener for RecyclerView. My expectation is a button "Load more" will display when user scroll to end of list. 
But I got a problem when getChildCount onScrolled() method:

```
@Override
    public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
        int totalItemCount = mLayoutManager.getItemCount();   
        int visibleItemCount = recyclerView.getChildCount();

        Log.d(TAG, "onScrolled:visibleItemCount "+visibleItemCount);

        if (loading && (totalItemCount > previousTotalItemCount)) {
            loading = false;
            previousTotalItemCount = totalItemCount;
        }

        if (!loading && (visibleItemCount + visibleThreshold) > totalItemCount) {
            currentPage++;
            onLoadMore(currentPage, totalItemCount);
            loading = true;
        }
    }
```

In the first log, visibleItemCount return the totalItemCount. For example:

onScrolled:visibleItemCount 20 
onScrolled:visibleItemCount 4 
etc, ....
Note: 
20 is total item; 
4 is the 4-th item that visible on screen